# python: using tempfile as a pipe

Tags: python, subprocess, temporary-files

TL;DR: how to get two INDEPENDENT file objects/descriptors of a tempfile (with no visible name)?

I have lots of data and need to pass to a command to process, i.e.

```
tmp = tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile()
p = subprocess.Popen(['command'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=tmp)
for d in get_data():
    p.stdin.write(d)
```

In this way, I cannot read `tmp` before `p` complete. I tried to get another descriptor of `tmp`, but seems impossible. `os.dup` doesn't help because the descriptor returned is just a reference.

NOTE: I cannot use `subprcess.PIPE` to stdout, because that may deadlock the process. I also don't want to use another thread to read as I want to keep the code simple.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to write to the stdin pipe?  Or are you trying to dump stdout to a tempfile and read the tempfile on the fly?

Comment: I want to dump stdout to a tempfile and read it on the fly.